# Dynamics CRM 2011 SOAP Service /web

Tags: soap, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a problem with my **SOAP-Service** of my **local** 
**Dynamics CRM 2011** installed on my **Windows Server 2008 R2 server**.

If I call my **SOAP-Service** with

```
"http://crmdevsvr/Contoso/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc"
```

or

```
"http://crmdevsvr/Contoso/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl"
```

It becomes a response.

Otherwise, if I call my **SOAP-Service** with my **Silverlight-Resource**, it builts internal with the function
**GetSoapService()** a **URL**

```
"Uri serviceUrl = CombineUrl(GetServerBaseUrl(), "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web");"
```

When I try to call the **URL** it doesn't work:

```
"http://crmdevsvr/Contoso/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web"
```

Now, the funny (or not) problem is, that the **URL** with end of **/web** only works **sometimes**.

What's the meaning of **/web** at the end of the **url**?

Comment: We are you using the /web at the end?

Comment: [MSDN Article on SOAP Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490657.aspx) is the article on this endpoint.  I'm sure you came across it already...but since I know nothing of this endpoint, I'm hoping someone will find it useful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I worked with the /web endpoint a while back, here is my understanding:

The OrganizationService is a server side endpoint, which means you need to reference it in your server side code first before you can call the web method. You can do this by adding the dll or the web reference to your project.

If you want to call the web method from client side, you need to use the /web one. It basically is a wrapper of the OrganizationService methods for JavaScript and Silverlight.